# Validating a form using data from data base

Tags: php, validation

i have a problem with proper validation. Please take o look on this class:

```
class NewFirm {
private $hookup;
private $tableMaster;
private $sql;

private $b1_name; //name of a Firm which has to be checked

public function __construct() {
    $this->hookup = UniversalConnect::doConnect();
    $this->tableMaster = "b1_firm";

    $this->b1_name = trim($_POST['b1_name']);

    $this->insertFirm();
    $this->hookup->close();

}

private function insertFirm() {

    try {
        $this->sql = "SELECT b1_name FROM $this->tableMaster WHERE b1_name = '".$this->b1_name."'";
        $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if((strtolower($row['b1_name']) != strtolower($this->b1_name))) {
                $this->sql = "INSERT INTO $this->tableMaster (b1_id, b1_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$this->b1_name."')";
                $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

                $this->sql = "SELECT MAX(b1_id) FROM $this->tableMaster";
                $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['b1_id'] = $row['MAX(b1_id)'];
                }

                $this->sql = "SELECT b1_name FROM $this->tableMaster WHERE b1_id = '".$_SESSION['b1_id']."' ";
                $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['b1_name'] = $row['b1_name'];
                }

                $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $uri = ''; //folder
                $page = 'step_2.php';
                header("Location: http://$host/$page");

            } else {
                $_SESSION['error'] = true;

                $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $uri = ''; //folder
                $page = 'step_1.php';
                header("Location: http://$host/$page");

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "There is a problem: ".$e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

}

When a firm name is found in the data base everything is ok. The problem appears when a new firm name isn't found in the data base - it shows a 'blank screen' :/

Comment: Dont forget use `exit();` after `header();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a flag to see if the contact is found or not, you can do something like redirecting to your first step where there is not contact found :

```
class NewFirm {
private $hookup;
private $tableMaster;
private $sql;

private $b1_name; //name of a Firm which has to be checked

public function __construct() {
    $this->hookup = UniversalConnect::doConnect();
    $this->tableMaster = "b1_firm";

    $this->b1_name = trim($_POST['b1_name']);

    $this->insertFirm();
    $this->hookup->close();

}

private function insertFirm() {

    try {
        $this->sql = "SELECT b1_name FROM $this->tableMaster WHERE b1_name = '".$this->b1_name."'";
        $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

        //setting a flag
        $not_found = true;

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //at least one contact was found
            $not_found = false;

            if((strtolower($row['b1_name']) != strtolower($this->b1_name))) {
                $this->sql = "INSERT INTO $this->tableMaster (b1_id, b1_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$this->b1_name."')";
                $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

                $this->sql = "SELECT MAX(b1_id) FROM $this->tableMaster";
                $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['b1_id'] = $row['MAX(b1_id)'];
                }

                $this->sql = "SELECT b1_name FROM $this->tableMaster WHERE b1_id = '".$_SESSION['b1_id']."' ";
                $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['b1_name'] = $row['b1_name'];
                }

                $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $uri = ''; //folder
                $page = 'step_2.php';
                header("Location: http://$host/$page");

            } else {
                $_SESSION['error'] = true;

                $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $uri = ''; //folder
                $page = 'step_1.php';
                header("Location: http://$host/$page");

            }
        }
        //if the contact was not found, redirect to the first step.
        if ($not_found){
            $_SESSION['error'] = true;

            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $uri = ''; //folder
            $page = 'step_1.php';
            header("Location: http://$host/$page");
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "There is a problem: ".$e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is -> when there's no record found in the database '$this->sql = "SELECT b1_name FROM $this->tableMaster WHERE b1_name = '".$this->b1_name."'";' it should pass the 'if' test 'if((strtolower($row['b1_name']) != strtolower($this->b1_name)))'. Instead, it appear a white screen :(

Comment: No, if there isn't any record, your program will never go into the while loop (because the fetch_assoc() will return directly false if there is no result). That's why I've added the flag permitting to test if no record has been returned by the query.

Comment: ok, I understand :) but I had an another idea: I have replaced the 'if' body 'strtolower($row['b1_name']) != strtolower($this->b1_name)' into '$result->num_rows == 0' and i have deleted the while loop -> now it works perfectly! Thx for Your advice!